# Stop VS installer updating itself

Tags: visual-studio

I have a limited data plan at my current location, which is extremely strict and impossible to change until I return to land. Large downloads, such as VS Installer updates, are prohibited - which is why I downloaded all the installation media I would need before this assignment. However, now that I need to install that media, Visual Studio Installer is demanding an update (or perhaps several). Not only is that impossible with my current data allowance, but will be intolerably slow over the satellite connection I currently am using (to say nothing of connection interrupts due to cloud cover, power loss, other crew requiring a connection etc).

I need to add some templating features to Visual Studio - this is an essential. How can I convince the installer to actually do what is advertised without first requiring it be updated? It refuses to even start if there is no network connection.

Comment: I know this post has no answer up to now - but have you figured out a way to work around your problem? / best case: disable the auto-update of vs_installer?

Comment: I never did. In fact, I actually spoke to an MSDN rep - who also had no idea. We actually had to shelve the project as a result, since the template was a highly complex structure that was unfeasible to recreate at the time. Sadly, this resulted in a significant monetary loss, and we've moved wholly away from Visual Studio as a result. Kinda embarrassing to be stuck on a ship for three weeks voluntarily not doing the job you were there to do...

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked the solution below:

```
vs_installer.exe --noUpdateInstaller
```

(Found the solution [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unattend-self-update-of-vs-installer/307261), which linked [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio) MSDN page).

Seems that specifying this flag **will indeed stop** the installer from self-updating.

Altho I'm not sure from which version this flag is supported.